# show / hide elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to display and hide images with a menu. How can I make this on to not show anything at start, and then show on click?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J3kjD/1/

I've got this HTML:

```
<div id="media" class="col-5">
    <img class="something" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    <img class="somethingelse" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>

<button data-id="something" class="test">Click!</button>
<button data-id="somethingelse" class="test">Click!</button>
```

CSS:

```
#media > img {
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function (e) {
    category = $(this).data('id');
    $('#media > img').css('display', 'none');
    $('#media > .' + category).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Not an answer, but a tip: jQuery provides the methods `.show()` and `.hide()` as a shortcut to manipulating the display property, and to ensure that when showing an element the proper display type is used.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have jQuery loading.

Comment: JAAulde, thanks I always forget about show()!

Answer (score 1):

You issue is that you have multiple class names assigned for the button where you need to take only the first one.

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function (e) {
    var category = "." + this.className.split(" ").shift(), $media = $('#media'); //Get the first class name from the class names of the element
     $media.children('img').css('display', 'none'); 
     //You can use $media.children('img').hide()
     $media.children(category).css('display', 'block'); 
     //You can use  $media.children(category).show()
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N8sr2/)**

Comment: Thanks, I actually did explain me a bit wrong, i'm getting the category variable from $(this).data('id'). Not the class. Sorry.

Comment: @Kim Whats wrong then? Your code in the question doesn't show it.

Comment: But thanks for your explaination! My problem now is that, I removed the css `display:none`so all images are showing at start. But if I click a button the images toggles perfect. But either `display:none` in css or `$(#media > img).hide()` works to "start" the toggles of the images on click

Comment: Yes, it was like that! But I made a new fiddle when I updated the question here => http://jsfiddle.net/BFjRd/1/ and it works! But it does not work in my original script..

Comment: @Kim one suggestion, sinc eyou are using data attr, just skip the string concatenation instead put the whole selector in the data like this http://jsfiddle.net/Zj8ux/

Comment: Thanks, But I checked in the inspector tool, and found out that the images I clicked to display had `display:none` so I tried add ing `width:100%; height:100%` and Voíla! it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using data-id attribute:

```
data-id="something"
```

Also, make sure you include jQuery in your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/BFjRd/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `class` attribute. Convention says we can add more CSS classes in any order as we want to this, which would be a problem if we assume a specific position in the value for the target image ID.

You can instead assign the image ID to the attribute `data-image` for the image and, say, the attribute `data-image-target` for the button. [Please see Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CU86F/1/)

For your HTML, you can have:

```
<div id="media">
  <img data-image="something" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
  <img data-image="somethingelse" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/100/" />
</div>

<button class="test" data-image-target="something">Click!</button>
<button class="test" data-image-target="somethingelse">Click!</button>
```

And for your JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function (e) {
  var target = $(this).attr('data-image-target');
  $('#media > img').css('display', 'none');
  $('#media > img[data-image=' + target + ']').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle needs to have jquery enabled for one thing.  You also want to just get the first class in the button.  So try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function (e) {
    category = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $('.' + category).css('display', 'none');
    $('.' + category).css('display', 'block');
});
```